# Device specific style loading in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an application in which I am using different views for mobile and desktop instead of going for responsive design. I am using server side rendering for my application.

Here is the code for browser starter file

```js
import React from "react";
import App from "../shared/App";
import MobApp from "../shared/MobApp";

hydrate(<BrowserRouter>{__IS_MOBILE__ ? <MobApp /> : <App />}</BrowserRouter>
```

Here I render 'MobApp' component in case the site is loaded on mobile and 'App' in case the site is loaded on desktop.

Here is a dummy code for 'MobApp' component

```js
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import Header from './views/Mobile/layouts/Header';

import './MobApp.scss';

export class MobApp extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <Header />
     </div>
   );
 }
}

export default MobApp
```

As it is clear I am using import for loading component level CSS. Now 'Header' component inside this has it's own CSS import.

**Problem** - 
If someone opens the site on desktop view, the code for 'MobApp' imports like MobApp.scss and all it's child components like 'Header' is also included. As a result I am able to get the CSS of mobile components on desktop.

What all approaches can I use to avoid this?

- I have read about conditional imports and will try them out but would like to know if there is something better out there.
- Also, let me know if I need to change the way I am adding CSS to my components or is there a more scalable way to do the same to avoid any future problems.